# How to get a latitude and longitude fields particular value of JSON in python 3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently working on extracting latitude and longitude values of "point" field from json . I want to store each field value in two new columns. 
The JSON in pandas dataframe is as follows:

```
    user_id                     timestamp   point
0   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486}
1   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486}
2   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486}
3   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486}
4   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486}
```

I tried in the following function and works:

```
row = test["point"][0]

type(row)

row["lat"]
```

But now I want to extract with the another function and I get the new columns with:

```
<function getLat at 0x0000000006AE2950>

<function getLon at 0x0000000006A58BF8>
```

The function is:

```
def getLat(point):
   return point["lat"]

def getLon(point):
   return point["lon"]

test["lat"] = test["point"].apply(lambda row: getLat)

test["lon"] = test["point"].apply(lambda row: getLon)
```

And I get the following table:

```
    user_id                     timestamp   point                   lat  lon
0   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486} <function getLat at 0x0000000006AE2950> <function getLon at 0x0000000006A58BF8>
1   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486} <function getLat at 0x0000000006AE2950> <function getLon at 0x0000000006A58BF8>
2   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486} <function getLat at 0x0000000006AE2950> <function getLon at 0x0000000006A58BF8>
3   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486} <function getLat at 0x0000000006AE2950> <function getLon at 0x0000000006A58BF8>
4   58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600    14567410    {'lon': 2.9546, 'lat': 41.5486} <function getLat at 0x0000000006AE2950> <function getLon at 0x0000000006A58BF8>
```

Where is my code incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: after extracting the json string from the dataframe you need to jsonify that so that python recognize it as a json object

Answer (score 1):

Use only function name:

```
test["lat"] = test["point"].apply(getLat)
```

It is same like:

```
test["lat"] = test["point"].apply(lambda x: getLat(x))
```

Or use only lambda function:

```
test["lat"] = test["point"].apply(lambda x: x["lat"])
print (test)
                    user_id  timestamp                            point  \
0  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  {'lat': 41.5486, 'lon': 2.9546}   
1  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  {'lat': 41.5486, 'lon': 2.9546}   
2  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  {'lat': 41.5486, 'lon': 2.9546}   
3  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  {'lat': 41.5486, 'lon': 2.9546}   
4  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  {'lat': 41.5486, 'lon': 2.9546}   

       lat  
0  41.5486  
1  41.5486  
2  41.5486  
3  41.5486  
4  41.5486
```

Solution with `DataFrame` constructor, [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) delete column in original DataFrame and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is for append to original:

```
test = test.join(pd.DataFrame(test.pop('point').values.tolist(), index=test.index))
print (test)
                    user_id  timestamp      lat     lon
0  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  41.5486  2.9546
1  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  41.5486  2.9546
2  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  41.5486  2.9546
3  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  41.5486  2.9546
4  58d3ac2de04bd5249b4f6600   14567410  41.5486  2.9546
```

---

Another idea is use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
import json

with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    d = json.load(data_file)

df = json_normalize(d)
print (df)
```